# PHP Move_uploaded_file function not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, file-upload

here is the HTML code for image upload

```
<form id="imageUpload" action="" class="form-horizontal form-material" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6">Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-line" name="portfolioimage">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6">Select Package</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="packageName">
                <option selected disabled>-- SELECT PACKAGE -- </option>
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        echo "<option>$row[1]</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="ADD" name="addbtn">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is my php code for uploading image as the package name and datetime stamps.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['addbtn']))
{
    $errors= array();
    $package_name = $_POST['packageName'];
    $query = "select id from packages where title='$package_name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $package_id = $row[0];
    $image=$_FILES['portfolioimage']['name'];
    // $file_size =$_FILES['portfolioimage']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['portfolioimage']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['portfolioimage']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['portfolioimage']['name'])));
    $file_tmp=$_FILES['portfolioimage']['tmp_name'];
    $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
       $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    
    // if($file_size > 2097152){
    //    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    // }
    $timestamp = date("mdYHis");
    $imageName = $package_name . $timestamp ."." . $file_ext;

    if(empty($errors)==true)
    {   
        $uploadDir = '../Admin/images/portfolio_images';
        $dest = $uploadDir . "/" . $imageName ;
        $moveIMG = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$dest);
        if($moveIMG){
            echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('Image  Moved') </script>";
        } else {
            echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('Move failed') </script>";
        }
        $str = "INSERT INTO portfolio_images (image,package_id) VALUES ('$imageName',$package_id)";
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$str);
            if($query == 1)
            {
                echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('Image  Uploaded') </script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo"<script language='javascript'> alert('".$str."') </script>";
            }
    }
    else
    {
       print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

the condition in if section $moveIMG gives false value.
tried different ways to store at the dest path but the after so many tries it didn't works. it worked with this same code on first submission  but now its not working.

May be one of you can find the error!!

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Anyway what does "not working" mean exactly? Do you see a specific error or warning, and/or any unexpected behaviour? Describe specifically what happens when you try to run the code. Do you have PHP set to log errors and warnings to a file? If so please check there for any errors e.g. about file permissions or similar. If you don't have error logging set up, please enable that and then check again.

Comment: And as per the docs, move_uploaded_file will also fail if PHP considers there to be a problem with the upload. But you don't seem to be checking for that. You need to be examining the contents of `$_FILES['portfolioimage']['error']`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php explains the error codes you might see there. See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Why bother with SQL injection when anyone with upload permissions can deploy their own code on the server and have the server execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! after so many digging and some suggestions by @ADyson in the comments.
Come to know that if you put conditions for the file size and checking for the file size you come up with the specific file size but to upload files greater then 2MB have to change php.init max_file_size also.
But still you cant't able to move files to the another folder that is move_uploaded_files() do. I dont know the way to change that but anyone knows that really will appreciated.